# AttributeError: 'Legend' object has no attribute 'draggable'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am using pydiffusion module to do plots related to diffusion. I tried to run the following code but i am getting the error mentioned in the subject.
I took the help of the google to add 'draggable()' but to no avail.
I don't have much resources for **pydiffusion**
Please give me your input. Thank you.
Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pydiffusion.core import DiffSystem
from pydiffusion.utils import step, mesh
from pydiffusion.simulation import mphSim
from pydiffusion.plot import profileplot, DCplot

diffsys = DiffSystem(Xr=[0, 1], X=[0, 1], DC=[1e-14, 1e-14], name='Constant D')
dis = mesh(0, 1000, 501)
profile_init = step(dis, 500, diffsys, name='Intitial step profile')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
ax1, ax2 = fig.add_subplot(121), fig.add_subplot(122)
ax1.set_title('Diffusion Coefficients', fontsize=15)
ax2.set_title('Initial Step Profile', fontsize=15)
DCplot(diffsys, ax1)
profileplot(profile_init, ax2)
```

output

> Meshing completed. Grid min=2.000, max=2.000

````
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-6c67cfa7613d> in <module>
      6 ax1.set_title('Diffusion Coefficients', fontsize=15)
      7 ax2.set_title('Initial Step Profile', fontsize=15)
----> 8 DCplot(diffsys, ax1)
      9 profileplot(profile_init, ax2)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydiffusion\plot.py in DCplot(diffsys, ax, err, **kwargs)
    206     leg = ax.legend(numpoints=1, fontsize=leg_fontsize)
    207     leg.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.0)
--> 208     leg.draggable()
    209     plt.tight_layout()
    210 

AttributeError: 'Legend' object has no attribute 'draggable'     ```


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
end of the error


**Below are the 'obtained plot' and 'expected plot'
[![obtained][1]][1]
[![Expected][2]][2]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkzMg.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QRMU.png**
````

Comment: `legend.Legend.draggable` is deprecated and replaced with `legend.Legend.set_draggable()` in matplotlib 3.1.0 in May 2019. I guess it's your case. Check the version. Obvious solution is to use older vesion of matplotlib to run the code.

Comment: @Poolka Thank you for the comment. I have not mentioned any code line of 'legend'. Can you please tell me where should I add this code mentioned by you? I am very new to DCplot and profileplot. Before i worked with plot but i don't know the syntax for them. Please provide me the exact code. Thank you

Comment: The problem is not about the code itself. It's about versions and compatibility. Check versions of `matplotlib` and `pydiffusion` currently in use. To solve the problem you should use older version of `matplotlib` (older than 3.1.0) OR newer version of `pydiffusion` (newest is 0.2.1 according to pypi.org). Both ways should help.

Comment: @Poolka Well. Currently, I am having a **matplotlib version of 3.1.0** and                **pydiffusion of 0.2.1**. Thank you

Comment: @Poolka The issue is solved, I had to update pydiffusion to 0.2.3. Thank you again for taking out your time to write here.